# What is the [question-tag] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I found a tag called "[question-tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/question-tag/info)".
I don't know what it's used for.
The only question that uses it is [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30431/alternative-ways-of-saying-right).
I think it should be deleted.

Comment: I think it is meant to represent [tag:tag-questions] and should be merged into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StoneyB suggested the tag be replaced with [tag-questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-questions), and [J.R. did just that](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/30431/revisions) several hours ago.

The tag is no more.  It has ceased to be.  It's expired and gone to meet its maker.  This is a late tag!

Case closed.